# Binding checkbox inside a blazor component and displaying summary on the parent component

Tags: blazor

I am following the example on below link:

http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4350/Blazor-Binding-Events-and-Parameters.aspx

On the first part there was a checkbox bound to the TaskItem's IsComplete property. On the latter part of the example the checkbox was removed.

I added the checkbox back on the child component (ToDoComponent) and added the summary (Task count and IsComplete count) on the ToDoPage component.

I can property add or delete a task on the UI but if I toggle the checkbox the count summary is not updating. I have to click the Add Task button first before the summary section is updated.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: you need to call `StateHasChanged()`

Comment: Can you post your code so we can be clear what the exact issue is?

Comment: Essentially the problem is that your example modifies the example that uses a nested component. The count is being tracked on the parent component. The parent component needs to be notified that a value is being changed on the child component. One way to do this is to use a method described here: "Implementing State Management In Blazor" http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4338/Implementing-State-Management-In-Blazor.aspx